# how to delete documents using term in lucene

Tags: java, lucene

I am trying to delete a document by using a term in lucene index. but the code that I made below isn't working. are there any suggestion of how can I perform deleting function in lucene index?

```
public class DocumentDelete {
public static void main(String[] args) {
File indexDir = new File("C:/Users/Raden/Documents/lucene/LuceneHibernate/adi");
Term term = new Term(FIELD_PATH, "compatible");
Directory directory = FSDirectory.getDirectory(indexDir);
IndexReader indexReader = IndexReader.open(directory);
indexReader.deleteDocuments(term);
indexReader.close();        
}
}
```

Comment: Your code looks good, hmm ...

Comment: The code does look fine. Maybe the index has a lock file that you should delete. If this does not work, please add to your question exactly how you see that the deletion fails.

Comment: is that term even matching any documents?  Do a search for that term first to see if you get any results back.

Comment: agreed, unless of course FIELD_PATH is actually in your code, and not a valid field string, like "title" etc

Comment: so anyway, I had resorted to delete a document in an index in lucene is to use a tool name luke http://code.google.com/p/luke/ .as I am a bit loss in using lucene API to delete it.but maybe if you kind enough then you could give me a sample source code of how to delete documents in lucene index. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
IndexReader indexReader = IndexReader.open(directory); // this one uses default readonly mode
```

instead use this:

```
IndexReader indexReader = IndexReader.open(directory, false); // this will open the index in edit mode and you can delete the index. . .
```

So you do not need any extra tool for deleting index contents. . .